# sub-algorithms using algorithmic, part a part b

Tags: numbering, algorithms

I am currently displaying algorithms in a sequence 1-9. Now I have for example algorithm 7 and I would like to name it algorithm 7a and the next one will be algorithm 7b and then algorithm 8 again. The following is the code that I use:

```
\captionof{algorithm}{Consistency checker}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{$\mathbf{Consistent}$}{H}
\ForEach {$n \in H$}    \Comment \emph{go through all the nodes in the graph H}
    \If {there exists a formula $\psi \in H(n)$ AND $\neg\psi \in H(n)$}
        \State \textbf{return} No;
    \EndIf  
\EndFor
\State \textbf{return} Yes;
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
```

Also I have the following:

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{algor}{%
\hrulefill\par\offinterlineskip\vskip1pt%
\textbf{#1#2}#3\offinterlineskip\hrulefill}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{algori}{singlelinecheck=off,format=algor,labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{style=algori}
```

I am using it without `\begin{algorithm}` because this way my algorithms follow onto next page nicely and they don't float around.

Can someone suggest a solution to have algorithm 7a and 7b in the sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following minimal example defines a `subalgorithms` environment with code taken verbatim from [`amsmath.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.dtx) (for the `subequations` environment). It allows the user to surround those `algorithm`s that should be sub-enumerated, intermixed with regularly-enumerated `algorithm`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm,caption}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{algor}{%
  \hrulefill\par\offinterlineskip\vskip1pt%
  \textbf{#1#2}#3\offinterlineskip\hrulefill}
\DeclareCaptionStyle{algori}{singlelinecheck=off,format=algor,labelsep=space}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{style=algori}

\newcounter{parentalgorithm}

\makeatletter
% Code taken from amsmath (http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.dtx)
% ===========================================================================================
%    \begin{environment}{subalgorithms}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newenvironment{subalgorithms}{%
%    \end{macrocode}
%    Before sending down the `algorithm' counter to the subordinate
%    level, add 1 using standard \cn{refstepcounter}.
%    \begin{macrocode}
  \refstepcounter{algorithm}%
%    \end{macrocode}
%    Define \cn{theparentalgorithm} equivalent to current
%    \cn{thealgorithm}. \cn{edef} is necessary to expand the current
%    value of the algorithm counter. This might in rare cases cause
%    something to blow up, in which case the user needs to add
%    \cn{protect}.
%    \begin{macrocode}
  \protected@edef\theparentalgorithm{\thealgorithm}%
  \setcounter{parentalgorithm}{\value{algorithm}}%
%    \end{macrocode}
%    And set the algorithm counter to 0, so that the normal incrementing
%    processes in the various algorithm environments will produce the
%    desired results.
%    \begin{macrocode}
  \setcounter{algorithm}{0}%
  \def\thealgorithm{\theparentalgorithm\alph{algorithm}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{algorithm}{\value{parentalgorithm}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\captionof{algorithm}{Consistency checker}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{$\mathbf{Consistent}$}{H}
    \For {$n \in H$}    \Comment \emph{go through all the nodes in the graph~$H$}
      \If {there exists a formula $\psi \in H(n)$ AND $\neg\psi \in H(n)$}
        \State \textbf{return} No;
      \EndIf
    \EndFor
    \State \textbf{return} Yes;
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\begin{subalgorithms}
\captionof{algorithm}{Consistency checker}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{$\mathbf{Consistent}$}{H}
    \For {$n \in H$}    \Comment \emph{go through all the nodes in the graph~$H$}
      \If {there exists a formula $\psi \in H(n)$ AND $\neg\psi \in H(n)$}
        \State \textbf{return} No;
      \EndIf
    \EndFor
    \State \textbf{return} Yes;
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\captionof{algorithm}{Consistency checker}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{$\mathbf{Consistent}$}{H}
    \For {$n \in H$}    \Comment \emph{go through all the nodes in the graph~$H$}
      \If {there exists a formula $\psi \in H(n)$ AND $\neg\psi \in H(n)$}
        \State \textbf{return} No;
      \EndIf
    \EndFor
    \State \textbf{return} Yes;
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{subalgorithms}

\captionof{algorithm}{Consistency checker}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{$\mathbf{Consistent}$}{H}
    \For {$n \in H$}    \Comment \emph{go through all the nodes in the graph~$H$}
      \If {there exists a formula $\psi \in H(n)$ AND $\neg\psi \in H(n)$}
        \State \textbf{return} No;
      \EndIf
    \EndFor
    \State \textbf{return} Yes;
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Note that placing `\captionof` outside of a containment (group or box) may cause reference problems.

Comment: referencing is not an issue, I need to get around what you wrote and test it. From what you presented it looks exactly what I need. Thanks

Comment: question is using \begin{subalgorithms}, will it allow to split the algorithm without floating around the page?

Comment: @aki2014: Yes. The `subalgorithms` environment merely sets up the counters and restores it at the end. It doesn't affect the `algorithmic` environment at all (which will still break across the page boundary).

Comment: Fantastic, works well. I am accepting your answer. However, I have one last question is it possible to have the algorithms listed for example; 1a,2a,1b,2b ?

Comment: @aki2014: Yes you can, but there's not a simple solution (I think). You may be better off asking a [follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk).